# Weird icon on notification bar

Tags: notification-bar, notification-icons

[image]

Any ideas as to what it is?
Its not a notification or an ongoing notification. 
Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 running Android 4.1.2

Comment: From the position (between Skype and Amazon), it looks like an app notification? It's strange if there's no notification on the notification panel though (AFAIK, it's impossible to have notification icon without content). Does it appear as soon as after rebooting the device? If not, is there a pattern when it appears? Is it possible to discard the notification through "discard all notifications" button on notification panel? (not sure if it's available on Galaxy Note though)

Comment: I just tried to clear out the notification bar and it disappeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just had the same question answered on another forum:  Its a notification from Greenify: opening Greenify showed that auto-hibernation was not currently working.  Greenify need to ensure that a notification is linked to the appearnace of the icon.

If you do not have Greenify installed then the mystery deepens...

Comment: I do have greenify installed, thanks for solving the mystery.